# Using Objects in Multi-input in angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How can i use

```
[{type:'Fred',link:'google.com'},
{type:'Ethel',link:'google.com'},
{type:'Rick',link:'google.com'},
{type:'Lucy',link:'google.com'}]
```

instead of

```
[Ethel,Rick,Lucy]
```

So now I see [object Object] in the URL input but I want to see the URL there.

I tried kids.url and kids.$.url but didn't worked

the original 
http://jsbin.com/yuyawo/6/edit?html,js,output

the one I tried

http://jsbin.com/qiyiku/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: My first impression is that you're probably going to want to create a custom directive for this that `requires: ngModel` and internally set's the model and view values. Don't have too much time to devote to this now, but that's where I'd start.